# "Error: API call to reports.activities.list failed with error: Bad Request" when getting Google Meet data (call duration) using Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-meet

I am trying to get Google Meet data:

> 1. Total call duration of user in the specified month
> 2. Number of calls made by user in the specified month

using the following code snippet:

```
function getMeetLogs() {

  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero-based, so add 1
  var userEmail = "123@gmail.com"; // Replace with the desired user's email address
  
  var options = {
    applicationName: "meet",
    eventName: "call_ended",
    filters: {
    date: currentYear + "-" + currentMonth.toString().padStart(2, "0"), // Format: YYYY-MM
    event_type: "call_ended",
    meeting_type: "video_call",
    initiator_email: userEmail
    },
    maxResults: 1000
    };


    var meetLogs = AdminReports.Activities.list("all", "meet", options);
    Logger.log(meetLogs);
    
    var callCount = meetLogs.items ? meetLogs.items.length : 0;
    var totalDuration = 0;

    if (callCount > 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < meetLogs.items.length; i++) {
       var callDuration = meetLogs.items[i].parameters.duration;
       totalDuration += callDuration ? callDuration : 0;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run it, I receive the `following error`:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to reports.activities.list
> failed with error: Bad Request at newMeetLogsToSheet(Code:39:40)

I thought this was a parameter issue, so I went through this **[Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet#call_ended)** to match the parameters, however, I am not able to get around it. The following sources can be helpful to find the solution:

1. [Google Meet Parameters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/meet)
2. [User Usage Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get)

Can you please assist me how to resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: I do think the error is related to the parameters, for example, I couldn't find `meeting_type` or `initiator_email` in the documentation, have you tried doing the request without specific parameters and see the result?

Comment: yes I tried but I could not find data about `call_duration`, `number of calls` for a specific user. I think `AdminReports.Activities.list` is not the correct method to get this data.

Comment: I have added relevant sources at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to give you an idea on how to navigate through the parameters you get in the response when you use the `activities.list` method. For more clarity, I added some comments to the script.

This script aims to get the number of calls a user made in a particular month and the number of minutes spent on calls during that month.

```
function getMeetLogs() {
  const userKey = 'test@domain.xyz';// Replace with the desired user's email address
  const applicationName = 'meet';
  var duration = [];
  var meets = [];

  var options = {eventName: "call_ended"};
  var meetLogs = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, options);

  for (var i = 0; i < meetLogs.items.length; i++) {
    var date = new Date(meetLogs.items[i].id.time);
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var param = meetLogs.items[i].events[0].parameters;
    //console.log(param)//here you can see all the event details

    if (month == 5) {//change 5 to the month number you're looking for

      //For each event, iterate and to determine the call duration if the event name is duration_seconds
      for (var j = 0; j < param.length; j++) {
        if (param[j].name == 'meeting_code') {
          meets.push(param[j].value)          
        }

        if (param[j].name == 'duration_seconds') {
          duration.push(parseInt(param[j].intValue))        
        }

      }
    }
  }

  //Counting unique meetings to avoid counting duplicate meet codes (recurring meetings have the same meeting code)
  let uniqueMeets = [...new Set(meets)].length
  let sum = 0;
  duration.forEach(num => {
    sum += num;
  })

  console.log("Total calls for user " + userKey + ": " + uniqueMeets)
  console.log("Total minutes in call for user " + userKey + ": " + sum/60)
}
```

#### References:

- [Call event - Endpoint left](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet#call_ended)
- [Activity JSON representation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list#activity)

Comment: So basically we're filtering the request for `eventName: "call_ended"` for a specific user and this returns [these](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet#call_ended) parameters which based in your request, we're only looking for `duration_seconds` and `meeting_code` to count how many meetings the user attended to, I made a small edit in my script to count unique meetings

Comment: Great, it works as intended. Thank you

Comment: can we do the same for Calls for the Day and Call Duration for the Day?